# Jenkins JUnit not finding results in XML file

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Good day all! So I have been trying different ways to format my XML automation test results for JUnit to pull from. I have been able to get it to find the file, but it says there are no results:

```
[Pipeline] junit
Recording test results
None of the test reports contained any result
[Pipeline]
```

The file in question is output from Unreal Automation tests, which is json format, and I have a function that transforms relevant data into XML, output like so (with 'project', as its still unannounced):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuite tests="3" failures="2" time="5.7150259017944336">
  <testcase name="Failing Test" classname="project.Failing Test" status="Fail">
    <failure>Fail</failure>
    <output message="Expected 'An Error occurred' to be true." type="Error">D:\project\Plugins\projectTests\Source\projectTests\Private\Examples\ExampleTests.cpp 32</output>
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="Communication States" classname="<project>.VoIP.Communication States" status="Fail">
    <failure>Fail</failure>
    <output message="req_sessiongroup_remove_session failed for 1001:Target Object Does Not Exist" type="Warning">D:\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Logging\LogMacros.cpp 92</output>
    <output message="Should be transmitting to World Channel after Joining. Aborting Test" type="Error">D:\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Logging\LogMacros.cpp 92</output>
    <output message="Uninitializing Vivox Client" type="Info">D:\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Logging\LogMacros.cpp 92</output>
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="Passing Test" classname="project.Passing Test" status="Success">
    <success>Success</success>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

What is JUnit looking for?!?!  `jUnit format only allows one <failure> child for each <testcase>`

I have had the output read Fail, failure, I've included it all in the tag, as well various other amalgamations I cannot remember. I am at a loss.....

Answer (score 0):

It seems your converter accidentally converted the project to an XML-Tag. A valid XML-representation would be this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuite tests="3" failures="2" time="5.7150259017944336">
  <testcase name="Failing Test" classname="project.Failing Test" status="Fail">
    <failure>Fail</failure>
    <output message="Expected 'An Error occurred' to be true." type="Error">D:\project\Plugins\projectTests\Source\projectTests\Private\Examples\ExampleTests.cpp 32</output>
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="Communication States" classname="project.VoIP.Communication States" status="Fail">
    <failure>Fail</failure>
    <output message="req_sessiongroup_remove_session failed for 1001:Target Object Does Not Exist" type="Warning">D:\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Logging\LogMacros.cpp 92</output>
    <output message="Should be transmitting to World Channel after Joining. Aborting Test" type="Error">D:\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Logging\LogMacros.cpp 92</output>
    <output message="Uninitializing Vivox Client" type="Info">D:\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Logging\LogMacros.cpp 92</output>
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="Passing Test" classname="project.Passing Test" status="Success">
    <success>Success</success>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

Comment: no, that was me redacting the project name. I guess I messed one. That is not present in the final output